# Read dotCover total coverage output from GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci, dotcover

I configured `dotCover` to be run from our GitLab CI server.
It correctly runs the tests, produces the required output and the CI is configured to store the coverage HTML output in the GitLab artifacts. This works flawlessly.

What I'm trying to do is to read the total coverage output from the dotCover.exe console runner and parse it in gitlab CI. I read the dotCover [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html) but I did not find a method to output a line containing the coverage to console. Gitlab CI can only read coverage values from the sdout of the ci job, matching it with a custom regex.

This is my `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AnalyseParams>
    <TargetExecutable>C:\NUnit\nunit3-console.exe</TargetExecutable>
    <TargetArguments>--agents=1 MyDll.Spec.dll MyDll2.Spec.dll</TargetArguments>
    <Output>cover/AppCoverageReport.html</Output>
    <ReportType>html</ReportType>
    <Scope>
        <ScopeEntry>MyApp\bin\x86\Release\net461\MyApp.*.dll</ScopeEntry>
        <ScopeEntry>MyApp\bin\x86\Release\net461\*.exe</ScopeEntry>
    </Scope>
    <Filters>
        <ExcludeFilters>
            <FilterEntry>
                <ModuleMask>*.Spec</ModuleMask>
            </FilterEntry>
        </ExcludeFilters>
    </Filters>
</AnalyseParams>
```

and I run it with .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
C:\dotCover\dotCover.exe analyse config.xml /TargetWorkingDir=.
```

Is there a way to view this value in GitLab CI? Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you

Comment: I had the same issue with jacoco. It also created an HTML file with coverage files, that I parsed with `xmllint` (under Linux). I strongly recommend avoiding regexp when it comes to xml/html.

Comment: @YanFoto Thank you for your input, this particular HTML is easy to parse, the total coverage is at the beginning in a JS section so I used a very simple regex: `/= \[\["Total",\d+\.?\d+/`, but I don't like this solution at all. I'll try with better parsing tool, `dotCover` is windows-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reading the HTML output file of `dotCover` and parsing the output.
Luckily the total coverage is at an easily parse-able portion of the output file. The coverage regex is

```
'/= \[\["Total",\d+\.?\d+/'
```

This is my final `.gitlab-ci.yml` file (for Windows runner, dotCover is windows-only):

```
my_job:
  # your job configuration
  # ...
  scripts:
    # build the solution here, ...
    - dotCover.exe analyse dotCover.xml /TargetWorkingDir=.
    - type cover\AppCoverageReport.html
  coverage: '/= \[\["Total",\d+\.?\d+/'
```

Not a very long-term solution but it works for now, at least until I update `dotCover`.